# How to Implement add/remove module/add-ins features in Software Package

Tags: c#, .net, software-distribution

We are planning to develop a WPF application which has two following requirements:

1. Application will allow user to install/uninstall different modules without changing default software installation.
2. Implement add-ins functionality like Microsoft Office has.

Please guide us the good way to implement above features and easily maintainable.

Regards,
Aman

Comment: There's tons of resources on the web explaining how to implement a plugin architecture in a .NET application, see [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5420/Creating-a-Flexible-Dynamic-Plugin-Architecture-un), [3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx), [4](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/implementing-a-plug-in-architecture-in-c/184403942) and so on. Please ask a question regarding specific implementation issues. For architecture advice, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you MEF (managed extensible framework) to easy install / uninstall modules.
The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating extensible applications.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/dd460648.aspx

MEF is included in .NET framework 4.0 and higher.

---

For more complex modules with UI interactions is better use some framework, for example [PRISM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx)